# Reference on $\mathcal{L}^p(I;X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am doing some reading on evolution equations, and $\mathcal{L}^p$ spaces with functions with values in a Banach space $X$ appears rather often. However I have not found a comprehensive reference about these spaces (I read the corresponding chapters in Evans' PDE and Yosida functional analysis, but both are rather sketchy).

So can someone point to a good reference on these spaces? I just want to see some proofs of the basic properties I need when dealing with evolution PDEs, e.g, separability, reflexivity, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral ?

Answer (score 1):

You should read **Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications II/A** (subtitle **Linear Monotone Operators**) by *Zeidler and Boron*. Sections 23.2 onwards have exactly what you want.

Comment: It's not entirely self-contained: One relevant proof is a (reasonably detailed) outline to be filled out as an exercise, and another contains a part whose justification is outsourced to other books (_Functional Analysis: Theory and Applications_ by R. E. Edwards or _Nichtlineare Operatorgleichungen und Operatordifferentialgleichungen_ by Gajewski, Gröger, and Zacharias). But this still seems like the nicest, most relevant source of the bunch, and you've even provided the relevant sections. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Lecture notes [Martingales in Banach Spaces](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~pisier/ihp-pisier.pdf) by Gilles Pisier carefully present the properties of Bochner spaces $L^p(I;X)$, including the properties you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend hunters pde lecture notes: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf